# Account Detail Page is not Refresh

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigation, lightningnavigation

I created a popup model using LWC when user click on a button in account detail Page in service console. .After model is closed service console detail page is not refresh(same page need to refresh). I used below code and **it is not working in service console**. I removed objectApiName and tested .But it's not working. Can someone please tell me what changes are required?

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'standard__recordPage',
    attributes: {
    recordId: this.objectId,
    objectApiName: this.objectApiName,
    actionName: 'view'
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It will not work on the same page.

I see two options here:

1. (Preferred) You need Aura to fire `$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();`. Aura should catch a custom event from LWC.
   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:refreshView/documentation
2. (Easy) Fire `window.location.reload();` in your LWC.
3. (Not Recommended) `eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");`

Comment: Thank You piotr Gajek ,I tried the second option it will refesh the whole page again.I only need to refresh account page